# Need some help to fit in variables in right way

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, nuxt.js

vue2-google-maps json how to format the input

lat, lon from db as decimal, send in json format

```js
computed: mapState({
 company: state => state.company.company
})

{{company.latitude}} 

<gmap-map :center="{ lat: 50.0200271000, lng: 8.8775603000 }"
works but I cant get it working like that:

<gmap-map :center="{ lat: company.latitude, lng: company.longitude }"
<gmap-map :center="{ lat: 'company.latitude', lng: 'company.longitude' }"

How to do it right? Thanks for support.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `store` like this.

```
computed: {
   latitude() {
       return this.$store.state.company.latitude;
   },
   longitude() {
       return this.$store.state.company.longitude;
   }
}

// Template
<gmap-map :center="{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }" />
```

Comment: Thanks so far..
I already have: 
computed: mapState({
      company: state => state.company.company
    }),

What i found was necessary to transfrom the decimal into a string.

:center="{lat: (company.latitude | make_string), lng: (company.longitude | make_string)}"

filters: {
      make_string: function (value) {
        if (!value) return ''
        value = value.toString()
        return value
      }
    },